# Unifying model and schema

Tags: typescript, mongoose, typescript-typings

Situation: Mongoose in Node.js and Typescript, in VS Code.

In the code that I inherited from a template, there is the following Typescript code:

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

export type UserModel = mongoose.Document & {
  firstName: string,
  lastName: string
};

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  firstName: String,
  lastName: String
});

export const User = mongoose.model("User", UsersSchema);
```

The above works. I use `User` whenever I need to invoke the collection's `find` or other methods. I use `UserModel` whenever I need to specify the type of, for example, a callback parameter to make use of Intellisense and compile time property checking. An example is:

```
 User.find((err, result: UserModel[])=> 
   { console.log(result[0].lastName); }
```

However, there is the chore to ensure `UserModel` is mirroring `UsersSchema` all the time. It becomes tedious when there are many properties.

Is there a more elegant way to make use of the schema to annotate types directly?

Comment: Why are you using `String` (the object) instead of `string` (the primitive) in schema? is this the Mongoose limitation? I haven't worked with it, so the question might be trivial, but anyway, this attracted my attention. upd: sorry, just understood.

Comment: Yes, the permitted SchemaTypes are with uppercase names. See http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html. It's new to me too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Code

Helper types system:

```
type SingleValueType<T> =   Object extends T ? any :
                            T extends typeof mongoose.SchemaTypes.Mixed ? any :
                            T extends typeof Date ? Date :
                            T extends {(...args: any[]): infer R} ? R :
                            T extends {new (...args:any[]): infer R} ? R : never;

type ValueType<T> =     T extends Array<infer R> ? Array<SingleValueType<R>> : SingleValueType<T>;
type DefaultType<T> =   T extends {(...args: any[]): infer R} ? R : T;

type FieldDescriptionType<T> =  [ValueType<T>] extends [never] ? 
                                    T extends {type: infer R, default: infer D} ? ValueType<R> | DefaultType<D> :
                                    T extends {type: infer R} ? ValueType<R> : never   
                                : ValueType<T>;

type FieldType<T> =     [FieldDescriptionType<T>] extends [never] ? 
                            T extends {[index: string]: any} ? docType<T> : never
                        : FieldDescriptionType<T>;

export type docType<T> = {
    [P in keyof T]: FieldType<T[P]>
}
```

Then, we can use this last type as following:

```
const userDoc = {
    data: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed,
    firstName: String,
    lastName: {type: String},
    index: Number,
    oAuth: { provider: String, id: String, wrong: '' },
    day: Date,
    flag: Boolean,
    itemNames: {type: [String], default: undefined},
    itemIds: {type: [Number]}
};

export type UserModel = mongoose.Document & docType<typeof userDoc>;
const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(userDoc);
export const User = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);

User.find((err, result: UserModel[])=> {
    console.log(result[0].data); // any, since it's Mixed in mongoose (would be unknown in TS 3.0)
    console.log(result[0].oAuth.provider); // string
    result[0].oAuth.wrong = ''; // error, wrong is never
    console.log(result[0].lastName); // string
    console.log(result[0].day); // Date
    console.log(result[0].flag); // boolean
    console.log(result[0].itemNames); // string[] | undefined
    console.log(result[0].itemIds); // number[]
});
```

---

### Explanation

The helper type consist of following parts.

The `SingleValueType<T>` is the type allowing us to get the real field type by its capitalized form (i.e. primitive by object) or instance by class; mechanics are based on [these officially available types.](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21847) This type itself is split into following parts:

- First, we have special treatment for `Mixed` schema type, since it must be immediately transformed to `any` (in TS 2.9) or to `unknown` (in TS 3.0). It could appear in two different ways: either explicitly stated, or as empty object literal; last case must be handled here, so we won't mix it with the subdocument property.
- Next, we have a special treatment for type `Date`, since `new Date()` gives us
  `Date`, but simply `Date()` gives us `string`, unlike most other classes. So, we
  just explicitly state what it should be.
- Next, if type `T`, used as parameter, is a function (i.e. has some
  call signature), the result must be the return type of this function.
  This is a way to get `string` from `String`, `number` from `Number`,
  and so on.
- Next, if `T` is a constructor type (i.e. has `new` signature), the
  result must be the return type of this constructor, i.e. the instance
  of class. This could be used to store arbitrary complex structures.
- Lastly, if nothing of previous can be used, i.e. `T` is neither a
  function nor a constructor type, we set the type as `never`, which is the only type extending `never` itself.

Types `ValueType` and `DefaultType` use different transformations, since they are set differently. `ValueType` handles its argument as either type itself (passed to `SingleValueType`), or as an array containing this type (so it gives us an array too). `DefaultType` just uses the return type of given function, or a given type itself, if it's not a function.

The `FieldType<T>` is the type which either uses `ValueType<T>` directly (if it can be applied, i.e. if it isn't `never`), or performs two additional checks:

- Field could state its type explicitly, using the `type` element (and possible the default value, too). If
  this is the case, we call `ValueType` on this element. This is the
  reason to have `ValueType` and `FieldType` split, because type can't
  be directly recursive.
- Field could itself be the schema object. In this case we just treat
  it as such and call `docType<T>` defined below.

Then, it is used in generic type `docType<T>`, which just maps every property of `T` to corresponding `FieldType`s.

Finally, in the real code, we store the schema into constant variable; the `docType` based on the type of this variable would be the document type.

Comment: Thanks. I gave it a try without understanding half of it. Is there a typo in the helper type? It won't compile. The first error is `error TS1005: ';' expected.` just before the word `extends`.

Comment: What TypeScript version do you use? It will work only since 2.8 - it's impossible to extract type from function/class before this.

Comment: Yes, it was a compiler version issue. But there is a slight problem. If `userDoc` has an object as a property, eg `oAuth: { provider: String, id: String }`, compiler will say "error TS2339: Property 'provider' does not exist on type 'never'". (It doesn't complain about `UserModel.oAuth`.) Is there a way to overcome this other than to flatten my model?

Comment: See the edit, I've looked into docs and tried to cover all possible cases.

Comment: It works beautifully! This is fantastic use of some exotic features of Typescript. What have you been reading? This answer deserves a medal. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I hit a new problem. For properties of type `Date`, they work ok except now the compiler treats them as strings instead of a `Date` object like previously when I was using separate model and schema. I checked the Mongo database and the value was stored as a Date field. I don't know enough about conditional types to fix this. Is it possible to preserve the `Date` type?  (PS: `Boolean` are still treated as `boolean` though.)

Comment: Seems we just have to handle it as a special case - I'll try to find a better way, but not sure if it exist. See the edit, I've added the line into `ResultType`.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again. How can I extend it to cover array of Number, eg `roles: [ { type: Number }]`. I tried various permutations without understanding them fully and none works.

Comment: I haven't found your usage in docs, but adapted the code to handle schemas like `{ roles: {type: [Number]} }` - see the edit.

Comment: It's getting complicated!  `{type: [Number]}` now works. But `Date` is broken. A `Date` method, eg `getTime()` results in "error TS2339: Property 'getTime' does not exist on type 'string | Date. Property 'getTime does not exist on type 'string'.".

Comment: Earlier, I modified your previous version by changing the default `never` to `any` and `[ { type: Number}]` worked. I supposed that was relaxing type checking?

Comment: Of course. In my suggestion, `never` is used in any unhandled case, just to indicate that something is either missing (as you found) or erroneous (as in example), and so we can't do anything with this value. `any`, conversely, allows us... well, anything, in fact. About `Date` - strange, because the code in answer do work just well, and `day` in result is of type `Date`. Could you show a part of your schema which breaks?

Comment: Found the problem with the date. I set a default. It works if it is `{ type: Date, default: new Date() }`.  It does not work if it is `{ type: Date, default: "2001-01-01" }`.  Latter works in previous version though.  Thanks for everything.